# How to make the UIPopOver origin at a same coordinate in the mainView even when I am moving its source button?

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have assigned the uipopover to a horizontally moving object. So when I keeps on moving the popover moves along with it. But I doesnt want it to move. Only want that bottom arrow to move and the popover origin should be same always. So it will appear like only the arrow is moving under it.

Can anyone know how to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not possible and so I created a view that will look exactly like the popover and now everything is working fine.